# Swift - Chunk array to different sizes

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this extension:

```
extension Array {
    func chunkedElements(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

This function splits the array by `size: Int`

How to make my first array to be fixed to 17 `Element` and the other arrays to be 25?

Comment: Use `dropFirst(17)` first (or same logic), then stride()?

Comment: Where and how? Can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: This is not clear, if the first chunk must be of 17 elements and the other ones of 25, what does the `size` parameter mean?

Comment: I need the extension to be modified for first array and the other arrays, but I don't know how is going to happen

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov You don't need to modify the extension. It already does part of what you need, exactly. What `Larme` is saying is that you should compose this with `dropFirst`. So first take your array, call it `array`, and drop its first 17 elements. On the remaining elements, chunk them into 25, as you already know how to do. Then just tack on the 17 elements at the start. Something along the lines of `[ Array(array.prefix(17)) ] + array.dropFirst(17).chunkElements(into: 25)`

Comment: @jawadAli Please don't add the iOS tag to questions that are not specifically targeting iOS. Swift also works on macOS and Linux, and this question concerns a feature of the language that would work on all platforms, not just iOS. It's a question about Swift, not about iOS. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted it in all one extension you could do something like:

```
let exampleArray = Array(1...15)

extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int, firstChunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let firstChunk = Array(self.prefix(firstChunkSize))
        let rest = Array(self.suffix(self.count - firstChunkSize))
        var chunkedArray = stride(from: 0, to: rest.count, by: size).map {
            Array(rest[$0..<Swift.min($0 + size, rest.count)])
        }
        chunkedArray.insert(firstChunk, at: 0)
        return chunkedArray
    }
}

print(exampleArray.chunked(into: 5, firstChunkSize: 2))
// Prints: [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: It should be: let rest = Array(self.suffix(self.count - Swift.min(self.count, firstChunkSize))) , otherwise crash with: Fatal error: Can't take a suffix of negative length from a collection

Comment: This code could really be improved by "outsourcing" the bulk of its operations to the existing `func chunkedElements(into size: Int) -> [[Element]]`. Otherwise you're just repeating yourself, increasing code complexity, line count, and opening yourself up the opportunity to have a bug in a piece of copied code, and having to hunt down all of its ever-so-slightly modified copies, and having to patch them all separately (invariably missing a few along the way).

Answer (score 1):

Drop first 17 and then use this extension

```
let result = Array(array.dropFirst(n))
 extension Array {
        func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
            return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
                Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please include it in the extension ?